# Django ORM query performance

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm, timeit

I am trying to find best  the django query for my Django app. I am using default Sqlite DB as backend. I am using  `timeit` to find time taken for query.

```py
>>> import timeit
>>>
>>> setup_arg = 'from .models import AwsConsoleAccess'
>>> stmt1 = """AwsConsoleAccess.objects.filter(request_id='8548a2d5-4bb7-4fa9-add2-a41219dc8785')"""
>>> stmt2 = """AwsConsoleAccess.objects.filter(request_id='8548a2d5-4bb7-4fa9-add2-a41219dc8785').values('status')"""
>>>
>>>
>>> print(timeit.timeit(setup=setup_arg, stmt=stmt1, number=100) * 1000, 'ms')
7.873513997765258 ms
>>> print(timeit.timeit(setup=setup_arg, stmt=stmt2, number=100) * 1000, 'ms')
11.816384001576807 ms
```

SQL query executed:

```py
>>> print(AwsConsoleAccess.objects.filter(request_id='8548a2d5-4bb7-4fa9-add2-a41219dc8785').query)
SELECT "aws_console_awsconsoleaccess"."created",.....(all fields) FROM "aws_console_awsconsoleaccess" WHERE "aws_console_awsconsoleaccess"."request_id" = 8548a2d54bb74fa9add2a41219dc8785
>>> print(AwsConsoleAccess.objects.filter(request_id='8548a2d5-4bb7-4fa9-add2-a41219dc8785').values('status').query)
SELECT "aws_console_awsconsoleaccess"."status" FROM "aws_console_awsconsoleaccess" WHERE "aws_console_awsconsoleaccess"."request_id" = 8548a2d54bb74fa9add2a41219dc8785
```

In theory `select field from table` should run faster than `select * from table` but my result are not reflecting it.

1. Did I do my testing properly?
2. Is there any other way to test the performance between two queries in Django ORM?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have not considered the fact that [QuerySets are lazy](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/queries/#querysets-are-lazy), that is when you create a queryset no actual query is made to the database. The query will run only when the results of the query are actually needed.

So when you write `Model.objects.filter(...)` all that does is create a query. You should instead force the evaluation of the queryset, for example by converting it to a list. This will actually run the query and give you more accurate results:

```
list(Model.objects.filter(...))
```